# Getting database connection marked as broken from Hikari Pool while consuming Kafka messages

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We have a Spring Boot microservices which is acting as consumer and a producer in the same time. By same time, I mean it is consuming on `@KafkaListener` and in that same Kafka thread(s), we're producing to other topic. We use three partitions and therefore concurrency set to three. While processing larger influx of Kafka messages we get various of connection pool and transactional exceptions.

Stack trace 1:

`HikariPool-1 - Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@31232d8f marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(17002) java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1048) at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeSQLStatement(OracleStatement.java:1507)`

Stack trace 2:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No value for key [HikariDataSource (null)] bound to thread at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:198) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion(JpaTransactionManager.java:628)`

We have a listener defined:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@Data
public class ConsumerMessengerNotifyMS {

    @Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @Autowired MessengerProcessor messengerProcessor;

    @KafkaListener(
            id= "messageReceiver",
            clientIdPrefix = "ConsumerMessengerNotifyMS",
            topics = "${path.to.topic}",
            groupId = "${kafka.consumer-groups[1]}",
            autoStartup = "${spring.kafka.consumer.auto-startup}",
            containerFactory = "myFactory"
            batch = "true",
            concurrency = "3")
    public void onMessage(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records) {
        messengerProcessor.process(records);
}
```

A component `messengerProcessor`:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MessengerProcessor {

    @Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @Autowired DeliveryService communicationDeliveryService;
    @Autowired NotificationService notificationService;
    @Autowired KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public void process(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records) {
       records.stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .map(
                           record -> {
                                try {
                                    return this.objectMapper.readValue(record.value(),    NotificationMessage.class);
                                } catch (JsonProcessingException jpe) {
                                    log.error("Error while deserializing Kafka Record {} to NotificationMessage with key {}:: ", record, record.key());
                                    return null;
                                }
                            })
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .map(communicationDeliveryService::processNotificationMessage)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList)
                    .forEach(dto -> {
                        ProducerRecord<Integer, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>("path.to.topic2", dto.getKey(), objectMapper.writeValueAsStrig(dto));
                        kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);
                      });
       
}
```

And finally in `processNotificationMessage` method which is only in a `@Service` class, we have single update query and a select query (fetching a dto for `topic2`).

```
@Override
@Transactional(transactionManager = "myTransactionManager")
public Dto processNotificationMessage(NotificationMessage notificationMessage) {
            Dto dto = new Dto();
            CommunicationStatus communicationStatus = CommunicationStatus.valeuOf(notificationMessage.getMessageStatus());
            String notificationId = notificationMessage.getOrderId();
            if (SMS.equals(notificationMessage.getMessageType())) {

                smsInfoRepository.updateStatus(communicationStatus,notificationId);
                DeliveryOrderHolder bySmsInfo = deliveryOrderRepository.findBySmsInfo_NotificationId(notificationId);
                //DeliveryOrderHolder is a an object with three properties
                dto.setInvoice(bySmsInfo.getInvoiceNumber());
                dto.setBatchId(bySmsInfo.getBatchId().longValue());
                dto.setKey(bySmsInfo.getId());
                
                                            
            } else if (EMAIL.equals(notificationMessage.getMessageType())) {
                emailInfoRepository.updateStatus(communicationStatus,notificationId);
                DeliveryOrderHolder byEmailInfo = deliveryOrderRepository.findByEmailInfo_NotificationId(notificationId);
                dto.setInvoice(byEmailInfo.getInvoiceNumber());
                dto.setBatchId(byEmailInfo.getBatchId().longValue());
                dto.setKey(byEmailInfo.getId());
            }
        return dto;
 }
```

Queries are simple jpql query & spring-data-query:

```
@Modifying
@Query("Update EmailInfo emailInfo set emailInfo.status = :newStatus where emailInfo.notificationId = :notifId")
 int updateStatus(@Param("newStatus") CommunicationStatus status, @Param("notifId") String notificationId);
```

This is how dummy producer looks like:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000L)
public void pushKafka(){

        Random rd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i<batchSizeEmail; i++){
            DtoMessage dtoMessage = new DtoMessage();
            dtoMessage.setMessageType(rd.nextBoolean() ? SMS : EMAIL );
            dtoMessage.setMessageStatus(rd.nextBoolean() ? FAILED : SUBMITED);
            dtoMessage.setOrderId(String.valueOf(i));
            dtoMessage.setReceivedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
            kafkaTemplate.send("topic1", i, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dtoMessage)); 

}
```

That is all it is about code and business logic. I made sure that data in db is correctly set for the test. Here is some config and project setup:

Spring Boot: `2.7.15`
Spring Kafka: `2.8.11`
org.apache.kafka - kafka-clients: `3.1.2`
Database: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Some list of dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
<!--            <exclusions>-->
<!--                <exclusion>-->
<!--                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>-->
<!--                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>-->
<!--                </exclusion>-->
<!--            </exclusions>-->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>21.1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
            <version>21.1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Config class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "myEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "myTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"root.package"})
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
       // OracleDataSource
//        PoolDataSource poolDataSource = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
//        poolDataSource.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
//        poolDataSource.setURL("url");
//        poolDataSource.setUser("user");
//        poolDataSource.setPassword("pass");
//        poolDataSource.setMaxStatements(10);
//        poolDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(10);
//        poolDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(30);
//        return poolDataSource;

         return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean("myEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean myEntityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.ORACLE);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ClassUtils.getPackageName(AllDomainEntity.class));
      
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "myTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager myTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) throws SQLException {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
    }

}
```

I have tried using UCP pool following this [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/configuring-the-oracle-jdbc-drivers-in-a-springboot-project-take-2). I have also tried specifying different transaction managers, like `DataSourceTransactionManager`, `JtaTransactionManager`. Tried using `@Transactional` with propagation level `REQUIRES_NEW`. Tried setting `@Transactional` on the listener [directly](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/tips.html#ex-jdbc-sync), also tried native sql queries in `@Query`, and with `jdbcTemplate`.

Exception starts appearing sometimes instantly and sometimes after few minutes of consuming. I've not tested this locally, only on dev test environment. Is there anything I'm missing? I expect that all kafka messages are processed, don't care about order of processing of kafka messages.

Comment: Did you test with concurrency 1? Did you test without kafka? Are you sure this is related?

Also it seems you should use ojdbc7 not ojdbc8 for this database version: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/JDBC-getting-started.html#GUID-926E5324-D89A-4A00-B1AE-975C1089F0EA

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment and suggestion. Haven't tried, will do in few hours. Is there any reason why you think that setting concurrency 3 is wrong? From spring-kafka 3.0.0 (I think) concurrency is set to 3 by default.

Comment: It's not wrong to use concurrency 3, but from your post I understood you expect this may cause the problem, so reducing to 1 may narrow it down

Comment: I get same: `WARN  [c.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection] SID= CID= [messageReceiver-1-C-1] HikariPool-1 - Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@5a4c2cda marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(17002)
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket closed
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:967) at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)`